# When I have migrate a db in ruby i got the follow error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'edu1.roles' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `roles`
/var/www/html/course/app/models/user.rb:12:in `<class:User>'
/var/www/html/course/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'edu1.roles' doesn't exist
/var/www/html/course/app/models/user.rb:12:in `<class:User>'
/var/www/html/course/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/course/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my roots.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/courses/all', to: 'courses#index_all'
  resources :courses

  patch 'courses/:id/enroll', to: 'courses#enroll', as: 'enroll_course'

  get 'categories/:category', to: 'courses#index', as: 'category'

  mount Upmin::Engine => '/admin'
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: can you post the code on your migration file?

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file? It's seems you refer to `User` model from `routes`.

Comment: @ganesan please add some details about your tables and their relationships

Comment: Details from `schema.rb` and the output of `$ rake db:migrate:status` might be helpful as well.